# Python Selenium a hidden frame that appears sometimes with java script assert

Tags: python, selenium, hidden, execute-script

I have a notification that appears in a couple of times a week on this website I scrape.  And I can't get around it.

I can run the code.

```
el =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnRead']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
```

Which clears it, but if I leave it in my code it gives me a no such element exception. Event if I try to wrap it in try/catch like so.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnRead']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print(nonefound)
sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

This also clears it, if it exists but if it doesn't, error.
I assume I am doing something wrong but I have tried a few different versions of this and I always get the error which leaves the windows hanging and stops the execution of the rest of the script.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793390/python-selenium-webdriver-to-check-if-element-does-not-exist-takes-time) will be your answer. Please try.

Comment: I tried this but I can't get it to work.  I appreciate that your help.  To clarify, I can find the element when it is there.  I just can't catch the error to stop the code from breaking when it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the length of the element in case you want to continue your scripts.

If length of the elements more that 0 this will click.

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnRead']"))>0 :
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnRead']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
else:
    print("nonefound")
```

---

Or induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
try:
    el = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("//input[@id='btnRead']")))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("nonefound")
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried a version of this before and must have messed up the code somewhere.  This solves my problem completely.  I just tested it 10 different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible there is another exception other than `NoSuchElementException`. The "hanging" could be from a `TimeoutException`. Try printing there exception like this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='btnRead']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", el)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```